# What is the best way to tessellate sphere into equal area in any level of detail? HEALPix or Geodesic Grid or another method?

Tags: geometry, spheres, geodesic, tessellations, cartography

I want to tessellate sphere into a grid in my 3D world map. There was 2 ways that I was consider right now, HEALPix and Geodesic

[image]
[image]

If I use it specifically for world map that could be zoom into any level of detail; What would be the better method and what is drawback or limitation of each method?